# Answer not really addressing original post but getting enormous vote-ups

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39727540/4373584) question on Stackoverflow has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39727783/4373584) posted which I believe is getting too much credit but not *really* addressing the actual issue (*at least in my opinion; experts are welcome to have their say*) that the owner of the post has sought solution for.

So my question in this regard is that, what to do if such a case occurs where an answer not worthy of the credit is *getting too much of the credit*.

Could it be the cause of some sort of cheating, or is it the viewers being too generous of giving vote-ups without thoroughly reading the answer.

Any help (especially from the experts at Stackoverflow and Meta) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: My advice: move on. Without substantial evidence of fraud there's no way of telling, and votes are a matter of opinion, which isn't always necessarily a matter of correctness. Votes are completely subjective thus claiming an answer *get's too much credit* or *isn't worthy of the credit* is also subjective.

Comment: Follow up; users shouldn't be penalized by something as subjective as *you don't deserve that!*. Our goal is to build a knowledge base for future readers, not to particularly help the OP or gain IIP. Move on.

Comment: I think they are getting too generous. :)

Comment: Well what can you say. The question has been edited several times yet there are still irrelevant tags in there. The system is failing in more ways than one in that question.

Comment: Well, thanks for all you guys and for the comments and suggestions you made. Anyway, it's something I can't do anything about. At least my anger over it is a bit mitigated now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That answer gained 6 votes over several days, at about 1-2 votes per day. You can verify this in [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39727783/timeline).

Generally, there are lots of reasons why people upvote answers, and one of them may be that even if it doesn't completly adress the question, it helped them.

I don't think there is fraud involved here, and the community seems to have taken a liking to the answer, so I'd say thats fair.